# Angular-UI-Router Resolve OR Location Change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to use a UI-Router STATE to retrieve objects via a promise BUT redirect to a different path if the promise fails OR no objects are returned?

I'm currently looking at only cached objects and boolean parameters, and only allowing my controller to render if the objects exist.  Unfortunately, this means the view could possibly be displayed while objects are loading (not good)...

```
.state("accountSelect", { url: ACCT_SELECT_URL, templateUrl: "views/account-select.html",
    resolve: {
        hasAccounts: function (currentUser, $location) {
            if (!currentUser.profile.hasAccounts) {
                $location.path(ACCT_CREATE_URL);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

And then the controller...

```
accountManagementService.getAccounts()
    .then(function (items) {
        vm.accounts = items;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Exception in accountCtrl.getAccounts()');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I would much rather do BOTH of these in the resolve... load the objects but redirect to a different state if no objects are returned (or for errors).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use a UI-Router STATE to retrieve objects via a
>   promise BUT redirect to a different path if the promise fails OR no
>   objects are returned?

As far as I know and can tell from the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) there is no graceful way to handle failed resolves. I have constructed a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLKl0jcJRB9asSIy2wm9?p=info) to demonstrate two of the ways I have found to tackle this type of problem.

I have found it possible to handle it by configuring the app either at run or wherever it is most convenient by listening for a state change error like so:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event){
  $state.go('error');
});
```

Or handling it in a service:

```
function testService($state){
  var service = {
    getSomething: getSomething
  };

  function getSomething(){
    try{
      throw 'It broke!';
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      $state.go('error');
    }
  }

  return service;
}
```